# how to send Devanagari Hindi text in php email?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using SMTP php email to send an email. It is working fine with English language email but not with Devanagari Language.
I am using the following code to send the email.

but it goes like this: à¤¹à¤®à¤¾à¤°à¥€ à¤¸à¤°à¥ à¤µà¤¿à¤¸ à¤†à¤ªà¤•à¥‹ à¤•à¥ˆà¤¸à¥€ à¤²à¤—à¥€

$body=$this->load->view('email/review/review_instent_hindi_supreme',$bodydata,TRUE);
                                        $sub='हमारी सर्विस आपको कैसी लगी ?';
                                    $this->sendMail1($email,$sub,$body);

I have mentioned  hor hindi language.

Anyone encountered a similer issue please help me.